# How to vertical align div

Tags: html, css, magento

I want the price to be on the same line, just above the View details button. I have tried:

```css
vertical-align: bottom
```

but no luck.
http://enterprise-demo.user.magentotrial.com/women/tops-blouses.html

Comment: Copy all of your div `.price-box` and paste inside the `.actions` div. That will solve your trouble

Comment: Oops, didn't see your comment, it's the best solution imo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also move your

```
<div class="price-box">
```

in your

```
<div class="action">
```

as his first child.

Answer (score 0):

Give each `div` some class like this:

```css
.element {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can alternate the HTML structure, then you can copy `div.price-box` into the `.actions` div, as Roy says.

Else, you can do

```css
.products-grid .price-box {
   position: absolute;
   width: 100%;
   bottom: 90px;
}
```

The prices are not aligned vertically with the "view detail" button because the `div.action` block has `position:absolute`. To make the price always be just above the "view detail" button, you can make it absolutely positioned.

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of ways of align vertically a div. The best way is learn the concepts about vertical aligning and use the best approach to your case. [This blog post](http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/vertical-centering/) shows 6 ways of doing that and has helped me a lot.